# Imutable delete/filter/remove Array Item by Index in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to delete an item by index in Typescript?

Like:

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

// how to remove index 2?
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which is immutable and takes indices as arguments:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function removeAt(arr, i) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i+1)];
}

console.log(...removeAt(arr, 0));
console.log(...removeAt(arr, 1));
console.log(...removeAt(arr, 2));
console.log(...removeAt(arr, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Imutable way with `.filter()`

You can use the `.filter()` method to filter out the item at a given index.

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const indexToDelete = 2

console.log( myArray.filter( (elem, i) => i !== indexToDelete) )
// Logs 'a', 'b', 'd'
```

This won't modify the original array.

#### Mutable way with `.splice()`

If you don't care that the original `myArray` is modified, you can to it like this:

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const indexToDelete = 2

myArray.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
console.log(myArray)
// Logs 'a', 'b', 'd'
```

Comment: and you can create method `deleteElem(elem:any)` with body `this.arr.splice(this.arr.findIndex(e => e == elem), 1);` if you want to also delete by element